ggplot access inherited data object in scale_y_continuous
I'm trying to access the data passed to a ggplot command in a scale_y_continuous 'layer'
diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Very Good"), carat > 2.8) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=table, y=price, fill=color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=table, group=color), 
            vjust=-0.5,
            position=position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve="single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, max(.$table) * 1.1))

However, it's saying:
Error: object '.' not found


Perhaps let expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1), add = 0)?

Looks like this is a duplicate, see linked post. We can access the data by wrapping ggplot lines into curly brackets: data %>% {ggplot(., ...) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, max(.$price) * 1.1))}

thanks, that's just what I was looking for

This doesn't directly answer your question, but to access the data, I'd make a plotdata dataframe then call that dataframe for setting limits:
plotdata <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Very Good"), carat > 2.8)

ggplot(plotdata, aes(...
  ...
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, max(plotdata$price) * 1.1))

Or we can use expansion:
diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut %in% c("Very Good"), carat > 2.8) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=table, y=price, fill=color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=table, group=color), 
            vjust=-0.5,
            position=position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve="single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)))


